# Dependency injection into AngularJS controller, can it be more simple?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In my app.ts , I have the following code right now:

```
.controller('aboutHelper', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function ($scope, sharedService) {
    var aboutContr = new Controllers.AboutController($scope, sharedService);
}])
```

*Controllers.AboutController* is my class which contains the actual logic for my controller.This way I have to type every dependency three times. This doesn't look very good.  **Is there a better way to do things?**

Thanks

Comment: You need to extract that logic into a service and inject that where it's needed, as opposed to instantiating a controller inside another controller

Comment: helpful : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdtVn_8K17E&hd=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `AboutController` you can define static property `$inject` ([read more here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dinjectannotation))

The controller would look like this then:

```
module Controllers {

    export class AboutController {

        static $inject = ["$scope", "sharedService"];   

        constructor($scope: IAboutScope, sharedService: ISharedService) {

        }        
    }
}
```

Then this controller would be registered for angular like this:

```
app.controller('aboutCtrl', Controllers.AboutController)
```

Comment: I have another, similar question. This is how I create my service:
        .service('sharedService', function () {
        this.fbServices = new Services.FbService();
    })
How could I write this part better?

Comment: You can just write: app.service('sharedService', Services.FbService); If you add any dependencies, you can use the very same setup with static $inject

Answer (score 1):

if you are worried about growing argument list, then you can use $inject.get()