# How can I tie in my controller classes in a module into my Javascript application with Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Here is what I have right now:

File: app.ts

```
var app = angular.module('app',
    [
        'access', // I have similar controllers as below for this module
        'admin'
    ])
```

File: admin.ts

```
angular.module('admin', [])
```

File: adminHomeController.ts

```
class AdminHomeController {
}
```

File: adminContentController.ts

```
class AdminContentController {
}
```

File: global.ts

```
interface IAdminContentControllerScope extends IAdminHomeControllerScope {
    content: AdminContentController;
}
```

Can someone explain to me how I should tie the controllers into my `admin` module?

Comment: `angular.module('admin').controller('AdminController', AdminHomeController)` should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either register the controller like this:

```
app.module('admin')
   .controller('adminCtrl', [() => return new AdminController();}]);
```

or more comfortable way:

```
app.module('admin')
   .controller('adminCtrl', AdminController);
```

In the second case you must define static `$inject = [];` in your controller. Read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24933601/dependency-injection-into-angularjs-controller-can-it-be-more-simple/24934131#24934131).